find the limit of the number sequence:
$$
x_n = \frac {1} {\sqrt[n] {n!}}
$$
My attempt is to prove that $n!$ is always larger than the $a^n$ (with $a$ as a given constant, a as large as possible) . So the limit would be like:
$$
0<\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n< \frac {1} {a}
$$
And as $a$ is as large as possible, $\frac {1} {a}$ approaches 0. So the $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$ would approaches 0.
I kinda got the result I want but wonder if there’s a more accurate way to present this?
Thanks a lot! Sorry for my kinda rough English because we do not study Calculus in English

Do you know Stirling's formula?

Alternatively, there is a theorem in Real Analysis that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} = e.$$

No, I haven't heard about Stirling's formula, could you give me more information or recommend any website to look that up ?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%28n%21%29%5E%281%2Fn%29+as+n+-%3E+infinity

Stirling's formula can be found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

@AnneBauval I think you had a comment up which is now deleted, probably some duplicate link which wasn't correct or something, so I have removed my comment.
